# how to arrange horizontal field manager at bottom of the screen? blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, alignment, field

i want to put a menu at the bottom of the blackberry, menu items added to horizontal field manager... how to place the menu at the bottom of the screen...

Comment: Take a look at MainScreen - it provides a "status" area at the bottom of the screen that you could put buttons into. This might be the fastest/easiest way to do what you want without messing with custom layout. http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html

Answer (score 7):

setStatus(your Horizontal field manager);

Comment: +1 i was stuck here for long time till i get through this question work like charm ..... cheers